# The scope issue of the FUN symbol in the .stab section of an ELF file

Tags: linker, elf

In an ELF file, the .stab section is a debugging information section, which stores some symbol table entries, used to record the source code structure of the program. Each symbol table entry has an n_type field, which indicates the type or attribute of the symbol. Among them, the symbol with the type FUN represents the function or program symbol.
My question is how to determine the range and internal symbols of a FUN from the .stab section, how to find the start and end address of a function, as well as its parameters, variables, and nested scopes

When I run "objdump -G obj/kern/kernel", I can't find the start and end address of the FUN
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPNCA.png)

Comment: The STABS debugging format hasn't been in use for the last 15 years. You must be working on some truly ancient system.

Comment: I'm studying a lab of mit, and I use this in class.